# What's the best way to move forward with a cat with CKD and gingivitis?

Tags: cats, diet, diseases, infections

I don't know where to start this story but I have had a terrible experience with multiple vets, and even now I get conflicting information from two different vets.

Two years ago, my now 11 year old female cat started to show signs of pain in her mouth after eating. I took her to the vet, and he said there is nothing wrong. So, I assumed it is okay. My cat kept struggling so I took her to another vet and the other vet said, she has a gum infection. After returning to the initial vet, he says yea she has gum disease and administers steroids and the cat becomes much better instantly. He says that the teeth can be removed, but there is no guarantee that it will resolve the situation. So, we didn't remove the teeth. Fast forward less than a year, after a few steroid injections, I go to another vet and this one mentions that the cat appears to have CKD and removes a few teeth, but in the process of anesthesia the cat was about to die, but somehow the vet saves the cat and he removes a couple of teeth to treat the abscess in the mouth. Following this he recommends feeding the cat exclusively renal food. I take the cat to this vet for three rounds treatments of antibiotics(amoxicillin), the cat initially gets better but then goes back to vomiting and eating less of the renal food.

Around a month ago, I decided to go to yet another vet after the cat started to vomit again. This vet gave her subQ fluids and recommended clindamycin and metro antibiotics, however, since my cat is aggressive I wasn't able to administer the medicine. Since this vet lives very far away, I am unable to go to him everyday twice a day for 7 days to get help in administering the medicine as the cat gets very stressed every time. I asked the other vet who did the surgery if he can, and he refused.

The latest blood test shows that the cat has a creatinine of 2.01 and urea of 52 and glucose 172. The vet who did the surgery says the cat should eat strictly the renal food and is against feeding any boiled chicken breast to my cat(even when she isnt eating anything else) and when I did that with both wet food(royal canin) and dry food(mera), the cat initially would eat but then stopped eating. She would just lick the wet food and leave it. So, I'd throw away the food because she just wouldn't eat it.

After the latest vet gave her subQ, I tried feeding my cat some yoghurt(just milk and probiotics and I am aware that there is high calcium in it, which isn't great for the kidneys), with the dry food to increase her water intake and get probiotics, since she wasn't drinking any. And after doing that it helped, she  was feeling better for a few weeks and started drinking much more water but then she stopped wanting yoghurt. So going back to the exclusively dry renal food, she is now vomiting every time I give her that(except if I introduce chicken breast into her diet) When I give her boiled chicken breast, she becomes super excited and happy.  She hasn't vomited when I give her chicken breast. When I told the vet who did the surgery that I am feeding her chicken breast, he went crazy and said it's very bad because the proteins in the chicken breast aren't digestible while the one in the dry food is. If you ask me if the cat isnt eating anything and is vomiting some other food, chicken breast is better than nothing but this vet thinks otherwise. He recommended an overnight IV with steroids, but my cat hates going to the vet and I cant imagine the stress of having her stay at the vets. As of today, the gum infection hasn't been treated properly and the CKD is just there, and I have no idea what to do anymore. It is really exhausting. I would really appreciate some insight into how I can move forward.

**Question 1:** How bad is boiled chicken breast for a cat with CKD, and in circumstances in which she isn't eating anything else?

**Question 2:** Is there another way to feed the cat probiotics in a form that the cat would be willing to consume it, if not yoghurt?

**Question 3:** If a cat with CKD isn't drinking plenty of fluids, wouldn't a diet exclusively composed of dry food exacerbate the kidneys?

**Question 4:** The course of events almost suggests that the gum disease caused CKD, perhaps through limiting water consumption due to pain when drinking and general infection. Is there research that supports this hypothesis?

**Question 5:** What is causing the cat to sometimes vomit the dry food? If it's stomach acid, then isn't the food designed to counter that by pH control?

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! I feel with you that getting different advice for each vet is very puzzling and frustrating. Because this is a Q&A website we need a question we can answer properly. Yours comes with different illnesses and additional some about food. I would recommend to split them into different questions and link them to each other (with the linking I could help if you like). At the line of "What is typical treatment of illness A?" and "What to do, if my cat vomits food B but the vet insists to feed it?" When linked you do not need to tell the story twice :) Best wishes!

Comment: Hi @Allerleirauh, thanks for the suggestions. Do you mean I open multiple question posts? The nature of CKD means its symptoms are multifaceted, so if the whole story isn't explained, I feel like it might not be an accurate answer. Perhaps I can cut down on the story telling of my experience and focus on the symptoms, if that would help the question garner a better response. Do you think that is better?

Comment: Yes, open multiple questions. Focus here at CKD asking for typical symptoms and treatment. Open another question for the vomiting part, linking to this one for the whole circumstances. You can even split the CKD one into one "What tests would confirm CKD in a cat?" and another "How to treat CKD in a cat?" So answers will be independent of your cat having CKD or not. Then it is useful for you but for others too :)

Comment: Okay ^^ Sorry for misleading you. Please use for each question a new time the "Ask" button. Link to this question, so you do not need to repeat the whole story. If I see the questions not linked, I will add the link :) If I would open the new questions, I would get the reputation points for it instead of you... But once opened by you I can edit and help and you get the points :)

Comment: Have you tried soaking the renal food in water to make a soft paste? If chewing hurts your cat, this could be a solution. Depending on the food content, it can take an hour or more to completely soak the food (the less grain content there is, the longer it needs to soak).

Comment: @Allerleirauh I will try and keep them all in one place for now, if it doesn't work out, I'll think about opening new questions.

Comment: @Elmy Yes, I used to do that, she used to like the soaked water in the kibbles, so she'd drink that and often leave the rest behind. So, I tried blending it all once. But, I think all the particles would just spread around her mouth when she consumed it and aggravate her more, so in the end it was easier to just eat the kibbles whole for the most part. Now she is eating her dry food, after I gave her chicken breast a few days ago.